# How to insert data into 3 custom objects using apex code

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I have 3 custom objects, Object1, Object2, Object3.
Object2 is the child of Object1.
Object3 is the child of Object2.

So I want to insert multiple records into Object1, Object2, Object3.???

Answer (score 1):

Well, have you actually tried anything?

Simplest action (without using advanced tricks like `upsert`, external ids etc) is to do it in correct sequence. On successful insert the Id of the record will be returned to the object and you can use it in the lookups to build the relationship.

```
Account a = new Account(Name = 'test acc');
insert a;

Contact c = new Contact(LastName = 'Test', AccountId = a.Id);
insert c;

AccountContactRole acr = new AccountContactRole(Role = 'President', AccountId = a.Id, ContactId = c.Id);
insert acr;
```

Alternative would be to do it in whatever order you want and later update the child records with proper references...